# XHTML 1.0 Transitional vs XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Tags: xhtml

In terms of SEO, for client point of view, should I use XHTML 1.0 Transitional or XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Why some people still use Transitional?

*Will we lose something if We use Transitional over Strict?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XHTML **Strict** forces you to use semantic markup, where as **Transitional** is a bit more flexible and still allows you to use legacy presentational elements like `<font>` and `<center>`.

People still use **Transitional** to maintain support older markup, but it doesn't make any difference to SEO.  **Strict** is considered better for encouraging more accessible XHTML and better separation of content and presentation.

Comment: I'd love to use Strict, except on XML documents "document.cookies does not exist" "document.write is not allowed", and when using AJAX libraries like jQuery, you'll find many methods with comments like "This method is not available on XML documents." or "Note: this method currently does not provide cross-platform support for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does not allow data to be attached via expando properties."

Answer (score 4):

In terms of SEO, no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any impact of using one or the other : **what really matters is content**, not (X)HTML (Strict/Transitional).

Answer (score 2):

Echo comments that shouldn't make a difference.

In my opinion its better to pick one and make sure your site validates against it.

Also note that can make ASP.NET spit out strict by the following in the web.config

`<system.web>
    <xhtmlConformance mode="Strict" />
</system.web>`

Answer (score 1):

This is a good article explaining differences:
http://24ways.org/2005/transitional-vs-strict-markup